# Adding a tooltip to a ComboBox in Excel with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've added two Dropdown (aka ComboBox) to a Sheet
[image]

Using this piece of code I can access the Dropdown but how can I add a tooltip on the Dropdown?

The best solution would be to show a different text for every item but if there is only an unique tooltip for the whole dropdown I can change it after selecting every item.

```
Sub DropDown1_Change()

    Dim s As Object
    Set s = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
    s.ToolTip = "Example"
    Debug.Print s.ControlFormat.Value

End Sub
```

Comment: ComboBoxes on the worksheet do not have a tooltip property however you could put them on a UserForm and set the `ControlTipText` property.

Comment: @ashleedawg: no, on the property I have just some Excel-style property, but no Visual Studio-style property. Nothing which is similar to a TooltipText..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a forms combobox, it would not have a tooltip capability, but you can make it look like it has a tool tip.

Place a hyperlink with a screen tip underneath the combobox, when you mouse over the combobox the screen tip will pop up.
You can place the hyperlink on many cells if you intend on stretching the combobox over many cells.

### Like this

[image]

Here is a 20 second clip
http://www.screencast.com/t/ZbkEOyXntItk

You can get the range of the combobox with application.caller.

Assign each combobox to this macro, then you would only need one macro.

```
Sub DoIt()
    Dim r As Range
    r = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=r, Address:=r, ScreenTip:="5435435345", TextToDisplay:="ddddddddddddddddddd"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! I've tried to make it with VBA but I need some help. Could you kindly have just a look? https://pastebin.com/VtGqAwJZ

Answer (score 0):

Following is my code:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Click()
   ' Adding new items
   ComboBox1.AddItem ("S")
   ComboBox1.AddItem ("M")

   If ComboBox1.Text = "S" Then  'Add your dropdown item here
   With Me.ComboBox1
   .ControlTipText = "Strong"  ' Add your text here
   End With
   End If
   If ComboBox1.Text = "M" Then   'Add your dropdown item here
   With Me.ComboBox1
   .ControlTipText = "Moderate" ' Add your text here
   End With
   End If

End Sub
```